# Select Remote View Programmatically

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I'm trying out Kendo Mobile. I'm really impressed with it so far.  I've read this [tutorial](http://docs.kendoui.com/tutorials/build-apps-with-kendo-ui-mobile) and am modifying it a bit for my needs.

I've added an additional element to the tabstrip to include a "login" view.  Because my login form is long and complex, I don't want the actual code in index.html.  So, I've included it in a separate html file : login.html.

Now, when the user clicks on the login icon on the tabstrip, the GUI automatically transitions to the login form.  All good.

When the GUI loads, I am using JS to detect if the user is logged in our not.  If not, I want the GUI to automatically load the login page.  I'm able to do that using Kendo's "navigate" function.  Unfortunately, that takes the user out of the layout from the main application page.  Is there anyway to have an external html page that when navigated to will contain the main applications layout?

```
<footer data-role="footer">
    <div data-role="tabstrip" id="defaultTabStrip">
        <a href="#home" data-icon="home">Home</a>        
        <a href="about.html" data-icon="about">Home</a>  
        <a href="#foo" data-icon="action">Foo</a>
        <a href="login.html" data-icon="settings">Home</a>  
    </div> 
</footer>
```

This properly loads the login.html page, but I have no GUI around it.  I'd like to navigate to this content, but inside my main layout.:

```
if ( ! loggedIn ) {
  app.navigate("login.html");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So ... this is awkward.

Now, when I use this :

```
if ( ! loggedIn ) {
```

app.navigate("login.html");
}

It all works properly.  I didn't do anything at all.  I just tried again later and the login page loaded properly within the GUI layout.  So, I guess we can consider this solved.